# Classify all the values such that one has a quasiconformal map.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

currently I have the following question in mind: For which pairs $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb R^2$ is the function given by
$$
f(z) = z^{\alpha} \overline{z}^{\beta},
$$
quasiconformal map from the plane to the plane.

**My attempt:** The easiest case is given by $(\alpha,\beta) = (1,0)$. Also we can rewrite $f_{\alpha,\beta}(z) = z^{\alpha-\beta} |z|^{2\beta}$ so we should exclude $\alpha = \beta$. Moreover, it should be easy to check that $f_{\alpha,\beta}(z) = z^{\alpha-\beta} |z|^{2\beta}$ is a bijection by definition if $\alpha \neq \beta$. Now calculating the derivatives, observe that one has
$$
\partial_z f(z) = \alpha z^{\alpha-1} \bar{z}^{\beta},
$$
and
$$
\partial_{\bar{z}} f(z) = z^{\alpha} \beta \bar{z}^{\beta-1}.
$$
Thus to check that $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ is quasiconformal we need to check whether
$$
D_f(z) = \frac{|\alpha|+|\beta|}{|\alpha|-|\beta|} < 1,
$$
which is the case iff $\{|\alpha| < |\beta|\}$ and we conclude that $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ is quasiconformal iff $\{|\alpha| < |\beta|\}$.

**Question:** Is this correct?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|\alpha| > |\beta|$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of a quasiconformal map? They standard definition requires qc maps to be homeomorphisms; when one drops this requirement, the terminology is "quasiregular."

Comment: @Martin R Yes that is a typo on my part. Also, we have the requirement that the map is a homeomorphism, was I too careless to check this? I would like to know the quasiregular case aswell but it should be then just given by above while for quasiconformal maps I need to update the above.

Comment: Yes, you are careless. What makes you think that $|\alpha|<|\beta|$ implies a homeomorphism? Try to construct a counter-example to this claim. Also, in general, the expression that you wrote for $f$ is not even a function. You should take your question more seriously.